# Why is this Gradle exec command failing when it works from command prompt?

Tags: gradle, build, cygwin, build.gradle

I have a gradle build script with this in it:

```
exec {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'C:/cygwin64/bin/bash', '-lc', "'file /cygdrive/c'"
}
```

This fails showing the following error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: file /cygdrive/c: No such file or directory
```

However executing this direct from command prompt seems to work fine:

```
PS D:\s\u\deployment\backend> cmd /c C:/cygwin64/bin/bash -lc 'file /cygdrive/c'
/cygdrive/c: directory
```

Why is this not working in my gradle script? Any suggestions on how I could make this work?

More generally, I'm wanting a way to execute arbitrary commands via cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
exec {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'C:/cygwin64/bin/bash', '-lc', 'file /cygdrive/c'
}
```

Without `"` around `'file /cygdrive/c'`.

Comment: Didn't occur to me to not try and mirror the quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested in the 'running arbitrary commands via cygwin' bit, I've ended up with:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
def isWindows() {
    return Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)
}

def runFromCommandLine (String... args) {
    List<String> arguments
    if (isWindows()) {
        arguments = ['cmd', '/c', 'C:/cygwin64/bin/bash', '--login', '-c', args.join(' ')].toList()
    }
    else {
        arguments = args.toList()
    }

    exec {
        commandLine arguments
    }
}    

// usage
runFromCommandLine('file', '/cygdrive/c')
```